# Cannot delete indents nor past insertion point

Tags: vim

When I enter insert mode, vim will not allow deleting text behind where I entered insert. Also when I use auto indent, I cannot delete the indentations that get automatically created.

I've tried a blank vimrc and even tried my own version of vim compiled from source. How can I delete properly in vim?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you attempting to delete them using backspace? Try `:set backspace=indent,eol,start`

By default you can't backspace over auto-indentation, previous edits or line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Try `:set nocompatible`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it in my gvim 7.3.x